# Find substring in a string containing special characters .Net

Tags: .net, string, substring, contains

I have a very long string - more than 20000 characters without spaces but with special sings as well. I want to check if this string contains another string. But using string.contains gives false even though I'm sure that this string is there.
The searched substring comes from a request - it's correct while checking with debugger.

Can it be caused by the string lengths or the fact that it contains special sings? ("" And ,)

Comment: The length of the string(s) should not be an issue but hidden characters can be. Unfortunately you will need to try to create a [mcve], because ultimately without one this answer is going to be "Can someone post all their guesses as to what might be the reason for this", and that's neither a good question nor good answers.

Answer (score 1):

It could be an encoding problem. As your very long string and searched string seem to come from different datasources you could check if they have the same encoding (UTF-8 is a good choice)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. Turned out it was adding ' after substring name. I've cleared my solution, rebuild, restarted VS and it went smoothly.